# Can the deviceID in a CommCare form submission be used to trace details about the submitting device?

Tags: commcare

When looking at a form submission on CommCareHQ, the Form Metadata includes a field called deviceID. Can this field be used to find additional information about the device, such as model number, serial number, etc.? If so, how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may be able to use online tools to lookup the deviceID/IMEI number. One tool that I found was: http://www.imei.info/. Enter the deviceID and you should see the phone specs.